# How can I convert this sql query that reorders items in a database to linq?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

I currently have a table where an item has a new order based on a column it's being sorted by. The goal of the sql statement is to reorder the table based on that sort column. The SQL Command currently works, but I have a lot of hard coded strings and I'm hoping to convert it to linq so it will be easier to test. The sql I have is below:

```
sql = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "UPDATE x SET
x.[{1}] = x.[RowNum] FROM (SELECT [{1}], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY
t.[{1}] ASC, t.[Modified] DESC) AS RowNum FROM {0} t INNER JOIN
tableTwo i ON t.TableTwoId = i.Id INNER JOIN {4} p ON t.{4}Id
= p.Id WHERE i.{2} = {3} and {3} <> '' ", tableName, sortColumn, tableTwoColumn, "{0}", tableThreeName);
```

I'm familiar with basic Linq, but I'm not sure how to convert things like ROW_NUMBER() and OVER to linq. I changed the table names for sample names, in case it's not perfect. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I usually get a list of columns names : string[] columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumns>().Select(x => x.ColumnName).ToArray().  Then I can lookup the column name and get index.  int index = columnNames.IndexOf("ColumnA");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linq is for *querying*, not *updating*. You could possibly use EF or some other framework to update data but, honestly, raw SQL is best for bulk updating.

I would say that having a "sort" column that's based on existing data (and thus needs to be updated periodically) seems superfluous. Why not just order the data by that column in your select queries?

Comment: A legacy portion of the application requires it to be in there.I agree having a sort column based on existing data is definitely not ideal. That's a good point about LINQ being primarily for querying.  I may try something as outlined in here with using entity framework. https://entityframework-extensions.net/bulk-update?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI3rWan5ny5wIVCNNkCh39PQL2EAAYASAAEgIMl_D_BwE